# Images not displaying in production

Tags: php

So I took my site live and I see there are images missing and I am unclear as to whether it is a permissions issue or I am not referencing the file structure correctly. In terms of file structure, this is the header.php file inside of includes folder inside of public_html:

```
<?php
        $companyName = 'MicroUrb';
        include('includes/arrays.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title><?php echo TITLE; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css">
</head>
<body id="final-example">
        <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="banner">
                        <a href="/" title="Return to Home">
                                <img src="assets/img/banner0.jpg" alt="MicroUrb">
                                <div id="banner__text-content">
                                        <h1 id="banner__title">MicroUrb</h1>
                                </div>

                        </a>
                </div><!-- banner -->

                        <div id="nav">
                                <?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?>
                        </div><!-- nav -->

                                <div class="content">
```

In terms of permissions, I followed this guide, the answer with 239 votes:

https://superuser.com/questions/19318/how-can-i-give-write-access-of-a-folder-to-all-users-in-linux

I have played around with adding forward slash and other derivations in the code and it has not changed anything. So its grabbing the styles inside of assets but its not grabbing the images inside the images folder which is inside of assets.

Comment: What does console say about images don't load?

Comment: If you use htaccess to create pretty urls, you should use absolute paths to your images and assets. Try putting a / in front, like so: <img src="/assets/img/banner0.jpg" alt="MicroUrb">. If this is relative to root, you should be fine.

Comment: @Оzgur, I get a 403 error in console.

Comment: Are you able to load any image directly by typing the full URL to it in the browser's address bar? For example, `https://www.example.com/images/foo.png` or `http://localhost:80/images/foo.png`

Comment: @j08691, No, I get a 403 error there as well. Starting to sound like file permission issue.

Comment: Using WinSCP will give you a clear GUI view of your permissions and user group assignments to check that there is no oversight of something not so obvious using terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research I learned that ownership should be $USER:www-data - your user = owner and the web server = group owner

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /path/to/your_site.com/
```

After performing the above command in terminal, I refreshed the page and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have SSH access, try this in terminal

```
chmod --reference=styles images
chown --reference=styles images
```

This will set same permissions and ownership of styles directory to images directory.

Also a good article for 403 error and permissions https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644980/why-am-i-seeing-a-403-forbidden-error-message